# Unable to get property 'showWaitScreenWithNoClose'

Tags: modal-dialog

```
var waitingDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('Your action is in progress...', "Please wait while we generate the tasks for you.");
```

error

> Unable to get property `showWaitScreenWithNoClose` of `undefined` or
>   `null` reference

I keep getting this error message, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems you are missing `SP.SOD.executeFunc`. Try following.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
    var waitingDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('Your action is in progress...', "Please wait while we generate the tasks for you.");
});
```

I have tried it and output is following

[image]

## Reason

`SP.UI.ModalDialog` execution must be delayed until `sp.js` and `SP.ClientContext` are loaded.